# Delete Contact list data without Name field

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

I have a query. I get the list of contacts from my mobile. I should not display the contacts listed without name.

Like contact like :  9966332211. Data like these should be deleted and should not display in contact list. How can i achive it. Contacts should have NAme and contact number.
I am working on UISearchBar. How can i filter the contact based on input in Searchbar.

Kindly suggest me few ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, if it isn't my apologies.

I do something similar when I am developing sites. I create another row in a database named "IsDeleted" when "IsDeleted" is set to 1, it is hidden away from everything, such as when I run this query:
"SELECT * FROM [Cake] WHERE Frosting = @Frosting AND IsDeleted = 0"
Then obviously it won't show in the results

So I'm guessing you could do something similar. 
Or set a variable that is

"if number != null && name != null then print"